# Remove elements from a 2D-list based on a 1D-list

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists

> List A (called a) : 2D list like this : [[1,'aaa'],[2,'bbb'],[3,'ccc'],[4,'ddd']]
>
> List B (called b) : 1D list like this : ['aaa','abc','cba','acb']

I want to remove elements from the list A based on the content of list B.
In the example, the expected result is :

> New List C (called c) : [[2,'bbb'],[3,'ccc'],[4,'ddd']] //Since there is no element 'bbb', 'ccc' or 'ddd' in the list B

I'm currently using the following code and I find it very slow :

```
c = []
for elem in a:
    if elem[1] not in b:
        c.append(elem)
```

Is there a better way to do this removal ? Is it better to create a new list and append elements or remove elements from the orignal list ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There's no `'ddd'` in list `B` either.

Comment: You could speed it up by making list B a dictionary

Comment: @RocketHazmat You're right! I've fix the mistake, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not much faster, but perhaps more clean using a list comprehension

```
c = [elem for elem in a if elem[1] not in b]
```

---

If `b` is very large, then converting to a set will speed things up significantly since lookups in lists are in linear time `O(n)` but lookups in sets are in constant time `O(1)`

```
b_set = set(b)
c = [elem for elem in a if elem[1] not in b_set]
```

---

If the index-1 elements of `a` (`'aaa', 'bbb',` etc) are **unique**, then this might be even faster because then we can use the [set difference operator](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) `-`

```
a_dict = {k: v for v, k in a}
b_set = set(b)

set_difference = a_dict.keys() - b_set
c = [(a_dict[k]: k) for k in set_difference]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know what a set was before.. My program is now 100x faster. The last method is not suited for my case but it can surely help others.